# I can't create a child in Firebase Database in a folder with a unique id, how to decide it?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database structure:
[image: My database structure]

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adYms.png)

My code where I try to add a child for database:

```
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
            appPermissions = new AppPermissions();
            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            retrofitAPI = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitClient().create(RetrofitAPI.class);
            googlePlaceModelList = new ArrayList<>();
            userSavedLocationId = new ArrayList<>();
            pricesStationPrices = new ArrayList<>();

            locationReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    .getReference("Places");
            userLocationReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    .getReference("Users").child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Saved Locations");
            pricesReference =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    .getReference("Places").child(googlePlaceModel.getPlaceId()).child("Prices");
       
      
        private void saveUserLocation(String placeId) {
            userSavedLocationId.add(placeId);
            userLocationReference.setValue(userSavedLocationId);
        }

        private void saveLocation(SavedPlaceModel savedPlaceModel) {
            locationReference.child(savedPlaceModel.getPlaceId()).setValue(savedPlaceModel);
        }

        private void getUserSavedLocation(){
            DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                    .child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Saved Locations");
            databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()){
                        for(DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String placeId = ds.getValue(String.class);
                            userSavedLocationId.add(placeId);
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                }
            });
        }
        public void onChangePricesClick(GooglePlaceModel googlePlaceModel){
            PricesChange pricesChange = new PricesChange();
            pricesChange.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "prices dialog");
        }
    }
}
```

In this code I successfully create a child in database in Place folder with PlaceId and information about them also create a folder with PlaceId's in folder Users using   `.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Saved Locations")` , but when I tried to create child in PlaceId using `.child(googlePlaceModel.getPlaceId()).child("Prices");` I have a problem, how to decide that?

I dont have problem with code when write this on function, forexample

```
 public void onChangePricesClick(GooglePlaceModel googlePlaceModel){
    PricesChange pricesChange = new PricesChange();
    pricesChange.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "prices dialog");

    pricesReference =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://gasapplication1-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app")
            .getReference("Places").child(googlePlaceModel.getPlaceId()).child("Prices");

}
```

but then code don't working and child is not creating

Comment: "I have a problem" What is that problem? Is there an error message?

Comment: problem "can't find symbol variable googlePlaceModel " , when I create local variable GooglePlaceModel project is not running

Comment: Where in your code are you getting "can't find symbol variable googlePlaceModel"?

Comment: pricesReference =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Places").child(googlePlaceModel.getPlaceId()).child("Prices");
       in this place i have "can't find symbol variable googlePlaceModel"